# Story about an online influencer whose image is taken over by her owner corporation after her death

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, virtual

I read this story online, probably in one of the bigger SF magazine sites, within the last year.
The story is told from the perspective of the celebrity's personal assistant, who also was in love with her. The corporation made a virtual avatar of the star, refused to admit her death, and took over all the assistant's accounts and passwords, etc. I believe the author identified as female.

Comment: There is of course "[The Girl Who Was Plugged In](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Girl_Who_Was_Plugged_In)" by James Tiptree, Jr.

Comment: There is an old (1980s) German short story called "Belinda Superstar" (or something very close to that) with that exact plot - except that she is a movie star and the corporation drives her to suicide to avoid paying her for using her likeness.